# Agrupar registos de tabelas distintas

Tags: sql

Como posso obter o numero de nomes identicos de 2 tabelas, cliente e fornecedores.

Ex: o resultado é

Nome.   Qtd

Joao.      2

Pedro.     15

Miguel.    7

O código Que tenho é o seguinte.

```
Select nome from fornecedores where ativo = 1
Union all
Select nome from clientes  where ativo = 1
```

Tentei o `count` mas nao funciona bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só usar o COUNT() junto com o GROUP BY

```
Select nome, count(nome) as qtd 
from fornecedores 
where ativo = 1 
group by nome;
Union all 
Select nome, count(nome) as qtd 
from clientes 
where ativo = 1
group by nome;
```

A função COUNT() está operando sobre o GROUP BY.
Assim que as tuplas com atributos iguais(no caso o atributo `nome`) forem agrupadas, o COUNT() vai retornar quantas tuplas obedeciam a condição.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT nome FROM `cliente` WHERE ativo = 1) as c,
    (SELECT nome FROM `fornecedor` WHERE ativo = 1) as f
) WHERE c.nome = f.nome
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    aux.nome,
    count(1) AS qtd 
FROM
    (SELECT f.nome FROM fornecedores AS f WHERE f.ativo = 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.nome FROM clientes AS c WHERE c.ativo = 1 ) AS aux
GROUP BY
    aux.nome;
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
SELECT
    nome,
    count(1) AS qtd 
FROM
    (SELECT nome FROM fornecedores WHERE ativo = 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nome FROM clientes WHERE ativo = 1 ) AS aux
GROUP BY
    nome;
```